# login control in asp.net how to keep information of current user?

Tags: c#, asp.net

login control in asp.net how to keep information of current user?
    We use session for keep information of current user , but loin control or membership, how to keep current user data?

What is the method؟

Answer (score 0):

```
MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();
//Get Username of Currently logged in user
string username = currentUser.UserName;
//Get UserId of Currently logged in user
string UserId = currentUser.ProviderUserKey.ToString();
```

By using above code we can get currently logged user in login control

Here i written much code like from Membership i am getting currently logged in username  no need to use MembershipUser event to get currently logged in user we have another simple way to get currently logged in username you just define like this in your page

```
string userName = Page.User.Identity.Name;
```

[Source](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/01/how-can-we-get-username-and-userid-of.html)

Comment: ok , but I want to know membership where keep current user data , and whats Way of doing it؟

Comment: use session , or other way?

Comment: membership gives you a built-in way to validate and store user credentials. ASP.NET membership therefore helps you manage user authentication in your Web sites. You can use ASP.NET membership with ASP.NET forms authentication by using with the ASP.NET login controls to create a complete system for authenticating users.